# Can Lync switch audio device for a call in progress?

Tags: lync

Microsoft Lync allows to select the primary communication device so I can switch between my USB headset and PC speaker/mic. But the settings is used for new calls only. Is there a possibility to change the communication device for a call in progress?

Comment: you should probably include which version and OS

Comment: I would be satisfied with any version allowing that. I have tried  on _Win7/Lync2010_ and _Win7/Lync2013_. I do not think the OS version is significant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Lync 2010, it seems to be possible to select a different audio or video device.

But the settings have no impact until you end the call, and re-establish it.

So, practically, **NO**.